# High resolution timer support on 64-bit Linux

Tags: linux, timer, 64-bit, linux-kernel

I'm trying to enable high resolution timer support on 2.6.39.1 64-bit Linux. To do this, I first set `CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y` in .config.

Also, the output of `grep HZ .config` is:

```
# CONFIG_RCU_FAST_NO_HZ is not set
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_250 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_300 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_1000=y
CONFIG_HZ=1000
CONFIG_MACHZ_WDT=m
```

However, the output of the following command is not `1 nsec` as expected after recompiling the kernel.

`cat /proc/timer_list |grep resolution` prints: `.resolution: 999848 nsecs`

Also, `cat /proc/timer_list |grep handler` outputs:

`event_handler:  tick_handle_periodic`, instead of `event_handler:  hrtimer_interrupt`

When I ran experiments using `hrtimer`, I obviously did not see nanosecond precision in the results.

I also tried running the C program mentioned [here](http://www.advenage.com/topics/linux-timer-interrupt-frequency.php) which is supposed to help determine Linux Kernel Timer Interrupt Frequency. The result of running the C program is as follows:

`kernel timer interrupt frequency is approx. 766 Hz`

I'm working on the [Dell Poweredge T710](http://www.dell.com/us/enterprise/p/poweredge-t710/pd) which, I believe, does have hardware support for high resolution timers(?)

Have I missed any step? Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Double check that your booted kernel's config matches the one you think you built.  `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS`

Comment: @BrianCain: `/boot> cat config-2.6.39.1|grep HIGH_RES`

CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y

Comment: The scheduler only runs every so often, so it's natural to not see the expected precision.

Comment: @user745878 that command does not match the one I gave you, though it is an improvement over the `.config.`.  Does yourkernel not have a `/proc/config.gz`?

Comment: @jørgensen -- True, but the problem I'm facing at the moment is that hrtimers _hasn't_ been enabled in spite of enabling necessary options. Please refer to [this](http://elinux.org/High_Resolution_Timers#How_To_Use) link which talks about how to setup hrtimer.

Comment: @BrianCain -- Nope, the file /proc/config.gz does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Turned out that I accidently always booted into `"failsafe"` mode which set quite a lot of kernel options. One of them was `"highres=off"`.

Might be useful to check `/proc/cmdline` just to be sure.